# Passing callback functions as arguments in vanilla JS ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working on an ajax function to retrieve info from the database. I set up the API and the ajax function does retrieve proper values, but the callback function I passed as an argument won't work on onreadystatechange.

Simplified Code below

```
function serializeArgs(args) {
  //Serialize Arguments
}
function callback(a) {  //The function to be called as callback
  //Process the response and add contents to the page
}

function getListData(callback) {
  var ajaxOptions = {
    action: "get_data",
  }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", apiurl, true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
  request.setRequestHeader("Accept-language", "en-US");
  request.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      callback(this.response);
    }
  };
  request.send(serializeArgs(ajaxOptions));
}
```

When I run the function, I get the error "TypeError: callback is not a function"

I have been struggling with this all day, but since I am not that experienced with ajax, I could not figure out why this is happening, and how to solve it. I have a hunch that it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of the ajax, but I'm not sure how I can work around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short reference for this error:

You usually get this error when the following happens:

- When a function call is made on a property of that simply isn’t a function.
- When a function call is made on an object type that doesn’t contain that function or method.
- When a function call is made on a built-in method that expects a callback function argument to be provided, but no such function exists.

I noticed the following in your ajax function:

Your parameter is named `callback`, just like your function `callback`. What your ajax function is trying to do is use the parameter `callback` as a function (not sure if you pass the function `callback` in as a parameter, if you do, then it's alright, but since I cannot see where you are calling `getListData` function, I can only guess you are calling it without passing the function `callback` as an argument).

```
//Your function callback is trying to access this parameter.
//So unless your actual function callback is being passed in as an argument,
//it's most likely trying to access your parameter even though it is NOT a function or it isn't even receiving a function as parameter
function getListData(callback)
function callback(a)
```

However if you are trying to simply access it as a function (and not as a callback) i'd recommend changing the parameter name or function name `callback`.

So to show an example:

First way of doing what you are trying to achieve (callback way).
Call your function this way:

```
getListData(callback)
```

Or do the following:

```
function getListData(changedParamName) {
   //this way you can now call your callback function and pass this.response to it
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Where  do you call the function `getListData`?

My guess is, that you call it like `getListData()` without passing the callback function.
if you call it like `getListData(callback)` it should work. Hard to say what happens without the full code example.

just for testing you also can change the line

```
function getListData(callback) {
```

to

```
function getListData() {
```

just to see if it works.

In the second szenario, you don't pass the callback, so when you call the `callback` function, Javascript will look for it in the parent scope.